# VSTO VB.NET Excel Chart, Subtitle for Chart - How to access chart text box from code?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

I have a chart in Excel that I'd like to use a subtitle on.  There is no SubTitle Property on the chart object, so I looked in the Excel User interface and found that you can only create a sub-title by using a text box.  The text box looks like its associated with the chart, not the worksheet, so how would I access that text box from code?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another possibility, and that is to include the subtitle in the chart title, for example:

```
Dim co As ChartObject

Set co = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
co.Chart.HasTitle = True
co.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "First Quarter Sales" & vbCrLf & "Subtitle"
co.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters(22, 8).Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
```

Comment: I had though of something along this route, but was hoping there was a way to hit the text box object.  I did implement this for now, with charttitle.position set to automatic.  It creates a decent title...